# Search and remove item from listbox

Tags: c#, .net, search, listbox

Is there a way to remove an item from a listbox based on a string?

I have been playing around for a few minutes and here is what i have so far but its not working

```
foreach(string file in LB_upload.Items)
{
    ftp.Upload(file);
    int x = LB_upload.Items.IndexOf(file);
    LB_upload.Items.RemoveAt(x);
}
```

I could just loop through each item but I wanted to do something a little more elegant

Comment: It's not working because you are changing the IEnumerable<String> that you're iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(LB_upload.Items.Count > 0)
{
  ftp.Upload(LB_upload.Items[0].ToString());
  LB_upload.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: I liked this one too but i think John kraft is the winner

Comment: I changed to this as the answer.  I had to add a this.refresh to show the updates of the box. The reason was because I wanted to 1) show that files were moving and 2 if there was a problem you would see what files are left.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, I'd do something like;

```
foreach(string file in LB_upload.Items)
{
  ftp.Upload(file);
}
LB_upload.Items.Clear();
```

The problem you are probably encountering is that you are altering the list while iterating over this.  This is a big no-no, and has been covered ad-nauseum on this site.

Comment: ha yea i guess this is the most elegant way (1 line of code).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the title of your question it sounds like you don't want to remove every item, just some of them. If that's the case:

```
for (int i = LB_upload.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (somecondition)
    {
        ftp.Upload(LB_upload.Items[i]);
        LB_upload.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```