# Why is ListBox.Items.IsReadOnly=true? (F#/Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, f#, listbox

I'm trying to remove some objects from a ListBox that I have created, and for some reason ListBox.Items.IsReadOnly is true.

The following calls don't work:

```
myListBox.Items.Add("whatever")
myListBox.Items.Add("stuff")
myListBox.Items.Remove("whatever")
```

I get an exception:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Operation not supported on read-only collection.
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.RemoveImpl(Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.RemoveInternal(Object value)
   at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.Remove(T value)
```

I can set ListBox.ItemsSource, but working with .Items is much easier. I'm creating the ListBox like this:

```
let mutable myListBox= new ListBox()
```

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of the F# syntax, but you should be setting the ListBox.ItemsSource.

If you create an `ObservableCollection` and then set that to the `ItemsSource` you can add and remove items from the collection and the list box will update automatically.

Comment: I'll try that... it's strange, because in C# Items.Remove/Items.RemoveAt seem to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400091/search-and-remove-item-from-listbox

Comment: @Mike - Agreed it's strange, but I'm not familiar enough with F# to be able to say why it's different.

Comment: Got this working by creating a new ObservableCollection, assigning it as the ItemsSource on my ListBox, and then manipulating that instead of Items. Still not sure why Items is read only, but hey, this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works fine for me:

```
open System.Windows.Controls
let l = ListBox()
l.Items.Add("An item")
l.Items.Add("Another item")
l.Items.Remove("An item")
```

Are you doing something else in between the creation of the list box and attempting to add items?

Comment: Other than assigning some properties of the ListBox (height, etc), no.